# 20.04 nvidia-driver-470 Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, xorg

After a recent system upgrade Xorg can no longer load the nvidia module.

At first I went to
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia
ran the

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

and followed the process of purging the existing drivers and installing the recommended drivers (for me, 470).

After a big long run and reboot, same thing.

tried,

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and a reboot, and still no go.
I don't know where X is looking for the driver, or why this process does not appear to be installing the X driver, but I don't know what more to do.

Comment: Disabled Secure Boot in UEFI and try again.

Comment: Are you sure the driver is installed. Eg. `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Ubuntu packages don't install the xorg drivers in a place where X will find them. By having

```
Section "Files"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
EndSection
```

in **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** X is able to find the drivers and load properly.

It's frustrating that the Ubuntu packages are built in a way that this manual intervention is required.